# Union of all preimages

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If I take the union of all preimages under a function $f$, then I get the domain of $f$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. To be precise: if $f$ is a function from $A$  to $B$, then$$A=\bigcup_{b\in B}f^{-1}\bigl(\{b\}\bigr).$$